# Is it possible to use \n or <br> in Yii2 Kartik GridView DataColumn title?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have a table with many colomns. It has a big lable strings and smal data strings, like 'Average usage time' and '55',

```
| Average usage time |
______________________
|                  55|
```

so i want to show label in a few lines, like

```
| Average|
|   usage|
|    time|
| _______|
|     55 |
```

to fit table into screen. Problem is that DataColumn ignore both '\n' symbol and br tags in label. Is there any way to do this?

DataColumn example:

```
[
'attribute' => 'avg_usage_time',
'label' => 'Average <br>usage time',
'vAlign'=>'middle',
'content' => function($model) {
    return number_format($model['avg_usage_time'], 0, '.', ' ');
    },
'pageSummary' => function ($summary, $data, $widget) {
    return (isset($summary) && is_numeric($summary)) ? number_format($summary, 0, '.', ' ') : 0;
    },
 ],
```

Comment: Instead of usign <br> in lable, try to set width of header and column.
Ex : **'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'40px'),**

Comment: It works, but may cause some problems in this oriject. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution 
please add type attribute.

```
[
'attribute' => 'avg_usage_time',
'label' => 'Average <br>usage time',
'type' => 'raw'
'vAlign'=>'middle',
'content' => function($model) {
    return number_format($model['avg_usage_time'], 0, '.', ' ');
    },
'pageSummary' => function ($summary, $data, $widget) {
    return (isset($summary) && is_numeric($summary)) ? number_format($summary, 0, '.', ' ') : 0;
    },
 ],
```

may it helps you. please add this `'type' => 'raw'` in attribute it allows to use html.

Answer (score 2):

`'type' => 'raw'` don't work. Use `'encodeLabel' => false` instead

```php
[
'attribute' => 'avg_usage_time',
'label' => 'Average <br>usage time',
'encodeLabel' => false,
'vAlign'=>'middle',
'content' => function($model) {
    return number_format($model['avg_usage_time'], 0, '.', ' ');
    },
'pageSummary' => function ($summary, $data, $widget) {
    return (isset($summary) && is_numeric($summary)) ? number_format($summary, 0, '.', ' ') : 0;
    },
 ],
```